# How to display the highest value from a random created list of numbers in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I m building kind of a game in Flash (AS3) where sound input (microphone) trigger a equalizer (the **micLevel.height** controls the height of a mask (showing the equalizer). The **activityLevel** of the microphone gives me a number ( 0 - 100 ) wich is displayed in textfield **prosent**. The contestant shout in the microphone and try to reach 100 ( I use the **mc.gain** to make it hard to reach 100 ). So far so good! I m pretty new to AS3 so I feel kind of lost.

I need to display the highest number they manage to reach and I want to have a time limit on this. **The highest sound level in lets say 5 seconds.**

Here is the code so far:

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

Security.showSettings("privacy");
mic.setLoopBack(true);

if(mic != null)
{
    mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showLevel);
}

function showLevel(e:Event)
{
    micLevel.height = mic.activityLevel * 6;
    //mic.gain = 1;
    //trace(mic.activityLevel);
    prosent.text = "Activity: " + String(mic.activityLevel) + "%";
}
```

I just need some code that grab the highest number from the text field "prosent" (with a time limit) and display it in a new text field.

Im sorry if I m unclear, but if anyone could help me out I would be very happy!

Br Harald

Answer (score 1):

Just create a variable that will be updated whenever the `micLevel.height` value is higher than it, e.g.

```
var highest:Number = 0;

function showLevel(e:Event):void
{
    if(micLevel.height > highest)
    {
        // The mic level was higher than the previous highest level.
        highest = micLevel.height;

        // Change your other text field to show the value of 'highest'.
        // ..
    }

    prosent.text = "Activity: " + String(mic.activityLevel) + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start a Timer to reset your highestLevel var.  This will show you then the highest level every 5 seconds.  You could add a timer start-stop button too if you wanted to keep one highest always showing.

Then in your showLevel function, use `Math.max()` to get the highest number (between current activity and recent highest)

```
var highestLevel:Number = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000); // fires every 5 seconds

function initLevels(e:TimerEvent){
  timer.stop(); // you could stop your timer here automatically and then use a button to start again
  highestLevel = 0;  // when timer fires restart your highestLevels var
}

function showLevel(e:Event) {
  highestLevel = Math.max(mic.activityLevel * 6, highestLevel);
  prosent.text = "Activity: " + String(highestLevel) + "%";
}

timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, initLevels);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showLevel);
```